# Authenticate Git virtual users via PAM

Tags: linux, git, pam

Can Git authenticate virtual users via PAM? In particular, would Git require some additional utility, such as `gitolite` or `gitosis`?

Comment: Since I require to authenticate Git users against a MySQL database, a simpler solution which doesn't require PAM can be applied: run git via HTTP protocol, served by Apache with modules auth_mysql and WebDAV. I haven't yet solved this simpler hypothetical way, but it seems I'm close. Here I discussed one of the troubles encountered:
http://www.mail-archive.com/git@vger.kernel.org/msg14449.html

Comment: Problem solved thanks to the discussion carried on the above mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't authenticate. Period.

Gitolite ([please don't use the now obsolete project gitosis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309)) is [only for authorization](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html).

As long as the listening service (ssh or apache) is able to:

- use PAM (like an `libapache2-mod-auth-pam` in "[Authenticate Apache using PAM](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/apachepam.htm)")
- call gitolite (as in [this configuration, L107](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L95-L107))

You can authenticate using PAM and authorize using Gitolite.